# Writing a string array to a File but it just prints System.String[]

Tags: c#

I have written this code but has some problems:

```
    const int maxPeopleInFile = 2;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\mytest\SortedTest.txt"))
    {
        string[] columnheaders = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
        List<string> listKeeper = new List<string>();
        int fileNumber = 1;

        while (reader.Peek() > 0)
        {
            string[] currentRowValues = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            string id = currentRowValues[2];

            if (listKeeper.Count < maxPeopleInFile || (listKeeper.Count() <= maxPeopleInFile && listKeeper.Contains(id)))
            {
                if (!listKeeper.Contains(id))
                {
                    listKeeper.Add(id);
                }

                var writer = File.CreateText("file_" + fileNumber + ".txt");
                writer.Write(currentRowValues);
                writer.Close();
            }
            else // new file
            {
                fileNumber++;
                listKeeper = new List<string>();
                var writer = File.CreateText("file_" + fileNumber + ".txt");
                writer.Write(currentRowValues);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problems:
1: The files generated don't have the line I have read in `string[] currentRowValues = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');` 
What is being written to the file is one line and it is the text `System.String[]`

Comment: `writer.Write(currentRowValues)` does not iterate the values; it basically does `currentRowValues.ToString()`, which is not what you want. But it isn't clear to me why you would split the line in the first place, if you just want to write it back again...

Comment: Have you tried using a string.Join statement like `writer.Write(string.Join("\\n", currentRowValues));`

Comment: Apart from the error in writing the array type instead of its content I think that your loop will never work. File.CreateText will overwrite the previous file with the same name. Your plan to store 2 people in a single file could not work.

Comment: @Steve : Yes you are correct. So far we fixed the first part with String.Join , but yes you are correct. How do you suggest to fix this one?

Comment: Use the StreamWriter class directly with the boolean Append flag set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `currentRowValues` won't be serialized back to a comma-separated list of values by just giving it to `FileStream.Write`, because it writes the return value of `ToString` which is the object type name.

One possible approach might be using `string.Join`:

```
writer.Write(string.Join(",", currentRowValues));
```

Comment: Is there any dangerous! corner cases with this? For example if the original file did not have any values for some of its parts, hmm but I guess then they will be "" in the array and then when we convert them back with Join, they turn out fine again ? Just thinking to make sure no tricky case happens later

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper No problem with that, it would result in an empty string array

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper Check this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/sOZHIH. It's a real-time demonstration of your concern :)

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper Correction: I wanted to say... *It would result in an empty string*

Comment: so it is fine, right? When we read it first, it is an empty string..when we join it back again it is an empty string

Answer (score 2):

Since `currentRowValues` is an array, this call

```
writer.Write(currentRowValues);
```

is equivalent to

```
writer.Write(currentRowValues.ToString());
```

which produces the output that you see (i.e. `System.String[]`) because `ToString()` does *not* iterate the individual string values.

You can write the whole array into a file in one shot using [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines("file_" + fileNumber + ".txt", currentRowValues);
```

> **(From a comment)** [I] want to put [the exact row that I have read from original file] in a new file exactly like it used to be in the original file

Then you should use `string.Join` to undo the effects of the `string.Split`:

```
writer.Write(string.Join(",", currentRowValues));
```

Comment: I think `currentRowValues` are just the fields of one line, so `WriteAllLines` does not help. I guess OP wants to join these fields again with comma or a different separator.

Comment: Yes, The exact row that I have read from original file, want it to put it in a new file exactly like it used to be in the original file

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in this snippet:

```
  writer.Write(currentRowValues);
```

try:

```
  writer.Write(currentRowValues[0]);
or 
  writer.Write(currentRowValues[1]);
```

depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `string` value to the `Write()` method, not a `string[]`.

I would suggest the following:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var currentValue in currentRowValues)
    builder.Append(currentValue);
writer.Write(builder.ToString());
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add the namespace to be able to use StringBuilder.